# Looping through category hierarchy

Tags: php, loops

JSON: http://pastebin.com/XjK1VKE3

I need to loop through each category and create a nested list like so:

```
Electronics(31110)
    Mobile & Accessories(31087)
        Mobile Accessories(31080)
            Cases & Covers(29808)
            Screen Guards(729)
            Mobile Accessories Combos(355)
            Cables(153)
            Chargers(21)
            Power Banks(9)
            Batteries(2)
            Selfie Stick(2)
            Mobile Lenses(1)
        Mobiles(7)
    Computers & Accessories(15)
    ...
 ...
```

My code which is starting to get ugly:

```
if ($object->frontend_filters[0]->values->cats) {
    foreach ($object->frontend_filters[0]->values->cats as $cat) {
        echo print_r($cat,1);
        if ($cat->cats) {
            foreach ($cat->cats as $subcat) {
                if ($subcat->cats) {
                    foreach ($subcat->cats as $subcat3) {
                        $results['categories'][$cat->name][$subcat->name][] = $subcat3->name;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $results['categories'][$cat->name][] = $subcat->name;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $results['categories'][$cat->name] = [];
        }
    }
}
```

How do I do this without creating `n` number of loops because I'm not sure how many levels deep it might be each time.

Comment: Have you tried using http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php - SPL RecursiveArrayIterator

Comment: @3zzy just following up here, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following function, see demo [here](http://www.angelcool.net/stackoverflow/31633658.php):

```
// convert your json to a php array
$data = json_decode($yourJson,true);

function doList($data)
{

    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($data as $i =>$value)
    {
      if(is_array($value))
      {
        doList($value);
      }
      else
      {
        if($i == 'name' && $value != 'All')
        {
          echo "<li>$value({$data['count']})</li>";
        }
      }

    }

    echo '</ul>';

}

doList($data);
```